# In WPF, is it possible to specify multiple routed events for a single event trigger?

Tags: wpf, xaml, routed-events, event-triggers

I have an event trigger that I want to be fired in response to two different routed events.  I don't want to repeat the event response code (in XAML) twice.  Can I specify multiple routed events for a single event trigger declaration?

Example of a single event:

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.MouseEnter">
        <--XAML MAGIC-->
        ...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry... WPF's implementation of the EventTrigger only allows one routed event.

Typically you would be firing a storyboard from a routed event. I would suggest the following compromise:

```
<!--Define a storyboard as a resource-->
<Storyboard x:Key="MyStoryboard1">
   <!--Many properties and etc...-->
</Storyboard>

<Style.Triggers>
   <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.MouseEnter">
      <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MyStoryboard1}">
         <!--Other properties/name if necessary-->
      </BeginStoryboard>
   </EventTrigger>
   <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.MouseDown">
      <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MyStoryboard1}">
         <!--Other properties/name if necessary-->
      </BeginStoryboard>
   </EventTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

The concept is to reduce duplicate code by sharing resources.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I can live with that.  It actually fits pretty well with my intentions.